# Login Security Javascript

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, encryption

The below javascript is very useful, however, when typing in the PassWords, how can I get it to show (**********), instead of showing the actual PassWord?

```
function LogIn(){
loggedin=false;
username="";
password="";
username=prompt("UserName:","");
//username=username.toLowerCase();
password=prompt("PassWord:","");
//password=password.toLowerCase();

if (username=="User-1" && password=="PassWord-1") { 
loggedin=true;
window.location="https://site-1.com";
}

if (username=="User-2" && password=="PassWord-2") {
loggedin=true;
window.location="https://site-2.com";
}

//if (loggedin==false) {
if (loggedin===false) {
alert("OOPS!");
}
}
```

Comment: Do it in HTML with input type password

Comment: So, I should replace the below line?

Comment: <form><input type=button value="AUTHORIZED AREA" onClick="LogIn()"></form>

Comment: You have no security if you make a redirection to a supposedly secret URL by checking for hardcoded passwords. Since JavaScript is delivered to the client browser any user can just look into the code (even if it is obfuscated) and determine the password that you're checking for. Also, since the URL that you send users to with correct credentials is also hardcoded, the same issue applies. Do the redirection only on the server and after the server validated the credentials. Also, the URLs have to be only accessible with a valid session that is set after proper authentication. ... so much wrong

Comment: The 2 UserNames & PassWords that are redirecting are using links that are Hidden.  I know that some people or bots know how to easily find those links.  However, the redirect pages Don't need high level PassWord protection.  Also, I changed the login button to say (1 & 2), and I changed the UserName & PassWord boxes  to  (1 & 2).  For More Secure Pages or Directories, I have those More Secure script / code!.  :--)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <label for="pass">Password (8 characters minimum):</label>
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="password"
           minlength="8" required>
</div>
```

Comment: I might stick with the original javascript, even though it Doesn't hide the PassWord..  Your html code is a lot different than what I have.  However, Thanks!  :--)